# changing the value of argument(list) in python

Tags: python, arguments

I wanted to change the value of the argument(list), 
so I wrote the code as follows, but it didn't work properly.

```
def add1(s): # s is a list
    for i in s:
        i += 1
```

So I changed the code as shown below, and it worked. 
However, I want to know why the first code didn't work properly.

```
def add1(s):
    for i in range(len(s)):
        s[i] += 1
```

If you know the reason and explain it, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Read this for a full explanation - https://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/

Comment: If you reassign `i` it will become a new reference to the new value. The old value still remains in memory and the reference in the list is still pointing to it.

Comment: Thank you all!! Now I understand.

Answer (score 0):

`i` is a local variable in the loop that's holding the number that `s` holds. Reassigning a variable doesn't effect the data that it held originally.

It's similar to how this doesn't change `a`:

```
a = 1
b = a  # This is somewhat what's happening with `for i`
b += 1  # And this is comparable to i += 1

print(a, b)  # Will print 1 2, not 2 2
```

Answer (score 0):

`int` values are immutable. You can't change the value of an existing `int`; you can only replace it with a different `int`. But that means you only change what the name `i` refers to, not the element of `s` used to initialize `i` in the first place.

In your first code, you make `i` reference a new `int`.

In your second code, you make a particular slot of `s` refer to a new instance of `int`.